# TSLint and VSCode Issues: All destructured elements are unused

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, tslint, macos-catalina

**Error 1:**

```
Type assertion using the '<>' syntax is forbidden. Use the 'as' syntax instead. (no-angle-bracket-type-assertion)tslint(1)
This assertion is unnecessary since it does not change the type of the expression. (no-unnecessary-type-assertion)tslint(1)
'SchemaForm' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here.ts(2749)
```

**Error 2:**

```
All destructured elements are unused.
```

**Error 3**

```
Cannot find name 'container'.
```

[image]

[image]

> What settings gone missing?

VSCode: `Latest Version`
OS: `Mac Catalina 10.15.3`

Comment: Is the name of your file ending with `.tsx`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSX syntax is only valid in a `.tsx` file. Since you are in a `.ts` file, typescript will try to interpret the `<>` as a type assertion not a JSX tag, and parsing goes bad from there. Change the extension and it should work

Comment: Wow, what a point. In `jest.config`, it is considering both `.ts` or `.tsx`. But didn't expect such a huge difference w.r.to jsx compilation